# C# MVC stops after model execution

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a problem that I can't understand:
My ajax sends information to my controller

```
function guardar_stag() {        
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Staging/guardar_stag_bd',
        data: "{'po':'" + po + "','estilo':'" + estilo + "','size':'" + size + "','quantity':'" + quantity + "','employee':'" + employee + "','fabric_percent':'" + fabric_percent + "','country':'" + country + "','color':'" + color + "','comentario':'" + comentarios + "'}",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function (result) {
            //IT DOESN'T GET HERE 
          }
    });
}
```

Then I handle the information in my controller, it takes all the values

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult guardar_stag_bd(string po, string estilo, string size, string quantity, string employee, string fabric_percent, string country, string color, string comentario)
    {
        string[] tallas = size.Split('*'), cantidades = quantity.Split('*'), empleados = employee.Split('*'), porcentajes = fabric_percent.Split('*'), paises = country.Split('*'), colores = color.Split('*');
        int total = 0, id_size, id_color, id_pais, id_percent;
        int summary = ds.buscar_id_summary(po, estilo);
        for (int i = 1; i < cantidades.Length; i++)+= Convert.ToInt32(cantidades[i]);
        }
        int id_empleado;
        ds.guardar_stag_bd(po, estilo, total, Convert.ToInt32(Session["id_usuario"]), summary, comentario);
        int id_stag = ds.obtener_ultimo_stag();
        for (int i = 1; i < cantidades.Length; i++){
            id_empleado = stag.obtener_id_empleado(empleados[i]);
            id_size = consultas.buscar_talla(tallas[i]);
            id_color = consultas.buscar_color(colores[i]);
            id_pais = consultas.buscar_id_pais(paises[i]);
            id_percent = consultas.buscar_percent(porcentajes[i]);
            stag.guardar_yarn(id_stag.ToString(), id_stag.ToString());           
        }
//FOR ENDS BUT NEVER GO TO THE NEXT LINE            
            Session["id_staging"] = id_stag;
            return Json("0", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I have to insert information into my DB with `guardar_yarn` but even after I go line by line in the model, it doesn't show any error nor does it insert, after the Dispose() it just ends and does not return to `return Json` line

```
  public void guardar_yarn(string staging, string talla)
        {
            Conexion con = new Conexion();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
                com.Connection = con.AbrirConexion();
                com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO yarn(yarn) values('"+ staging+"') "; 
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
                finally { con.CerrarConexion(); con.Dispose(); } 
//it stops after this line and goes to the html page
            }
```

Sorry for my poor explanation, English is not my first language. Thanks

Comment: Looks like there is an error thrown from Finally block. You need to use try catch blocks in controller action and see if you are catching any exception there

Comment: Thank you very much, the table had no identity, it happened after the back up.